# Second Like/Unlike button with acts_as_votable gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed the [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) gem and I am trying to implement two buttons, one for liking a pin and one for unliking a pin. I already managed to create a button to like a pin and this is working. However, when I now try to add the second button, I get stuck. Any help much appreciated!!

My pins index view

```
<div class="actions">
   <% if user.likes? @pin%>
       <%= link_to unlike_pin_path(pin), method: :put, remote: true, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
       <% end %>
   <% else %>
      <%= link_to like_pin_path(pin), method: :put, remote: true, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></span>I like
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

And my pins controller:

```
def like
  @pin.liked_by current_user
  redirect_to :back
end

def unlike
  @pin.unliked_by current_user
  redirect_to :back
end
```

Comment: Would you mind to mention which part of your code doesn't work as wanted? Maybe you could reduce the amount of code in the view for this question too. The fewer code someone has to review to higher is the chance you get a quick answer.

Comment: Edit: I have tried to make the code looks shorter and easier to read. I get an error on the if condition <% if user.likes? @pin%>. However, according to the documentation https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable this should be correct. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: btw, I want to make sure that a user who has already voted, is not shown the vote button, but the unvote button instead and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The acts_as_votable gem doesn't provide a `likes?` method. It does provide a `liked?` method. Without having it tested I guess you want to use the following code:

```
<div class="actions">
  <% if user.liked? @pin %>
   <%= link_to unlike_pin_path(pin), method: :put, remote: true, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
  <% end %>
  <% else %>
  <%= link_to like_pin_path(pin), method: :put, remote: true, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></span>I like
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately i still get an error: undefined local variable or method `user' for #<#<Class:0x52556b8>:0x4c182d8>

Comment: That is a different problem => new question. In case this is a partial, you need to call the partial including the local variables. If it is not a partial you probably want to use @user. Please accept this answer and create a new question.

Comment: I changed the code into <% if current_user.liked? @pin %> and now it is working! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For `unlike_pin_path`, make sure your `routes.rb` file has the following:

```
resources :pins do
  member do
    put "like", to: "pins#upvote"
    put "unlike", to: "pins#downvote"
  end
end
```